# Weight vector always points to the positive side for a decision plane passing through origin

Tags: binary, classification

I have a decision boundary(e.g.) :

```
5 x1 + x2 - 3 = 0
```

with the weight vector being `[5 1]`.
To decide if a point in this plane lies on the positive or negative side of the boundary we can plug in that point in the equation and check if it is positive. 
But can it be proved mathematically that if a decision plane passes through the origin then the weight vector always points towards the positive side?

I searched several sites and found one (http://www.cs.utah.edu/~piyush/teaching/8-9-print.pdf) where it is said that the weight vector is assumed to always point towards positive side but did not find a mathematical proof for it.

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the thread, but maybe can help someone else. Indeed, you will find many sources which say it "has" to be on the positive side, but they never really show why. To prove this, there have to be some constraints, as opposed to some arbitrary hyperplane in an arbitrary vector space. I am certain, since you are talking about decision boundaries, that you are in the context of parameter space for say, perceptron, or something of the like. The parameter space is unique because hyperplanes always go through the origin. Why? Because the bias term itself is a dimension in the parameter space. It is no longer a constant offset. In parameter space, we have a unique construction of a hyperplane. The coefficients of the hyperplane's dimensions are the features in a vector x, including a bias dimension. Consider the definition of a hyperplane:

w*x + w0 = 0

I want to give a two dimensional example to illustrate a concept, and then quickly jump back to arbitrary dimensionality to be more general. For a two-dimensional example, you will have w0 vs w1.

Suppose you have two features:

x1 = 2

x2 = -1

If you were to plot these features in parameter space, you would construct them as [x 1], resulting in:

x1 -> [2 1]

x2 -> [-1 1]

and this would result in hyperplanes in the parameter space (weight space) as:

x1 ->  (2)w1 + (1)w0 = 0

x2 -> (-1)w1 + (1)w0 = 0

In our two dimensional example, we treat w0 and w1 as our tradition y vs. x and solve for "y".

[Parameter hyperplanes sketched in parameter space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW0d5.png)

Now, you can see the parameter vector (weight vector) point for one of the lines

[Parameter hyperplane with parameter vector point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Rqs.png)

You can see that the positive side and negative side of the hyperplanes are marked. So think about what makes the positive and negative side. Well, it's with respect to w0. We say it is the positive side of the hyperplane if it is a value of w0 which is greater than the value of w0 on the hyperplane (and the opposite for negative). Now, another crucial thing to understand is that all the parameter points must go through the line w0=1. This can be seen below:

[Parameter hyperplanes with parameter vector points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efbPj.png)

Now, we make an intuitive statement since we known positive or negative side depends on w0. Considering x to be an arbitrary sized vector of features. "If the value of w0 of the parameter vector, x, is greater than the value of w0 on the hyperplane evaluated at the location of x, then we are on the positive side of the hyperplane." Remember, w0 at the location x is always 1. So, what is the value of w0 on the hyperplane?

w*x + w0 = 0      ->   w0 = -w*x

The value of w0 on the hyperplane is -w*x. Now, if we want to evaluate the value of w0 on the hyperplane at the vector x, we have

w0 = -x*x

-x*x = -<x, x> = -||x||^2

We know the inner product, and equivalently the norm squared have to be positive or zero. Thus, a negative times that value has to be a negative number or zero. Thus, w0 <= 0 when evaluated on the hyperplane at location x. Remember, at that same location x, not on the hyperplane, the parameter vector told us w0 = 1. Since 1 is always greater than a negative number or zero, the parameter vector location of w0 is always higher than the decision boundary with respect to w0. This proof is constrained to the decision boundary going through the origin, but the decision boundary is guaranteed to go through the origin in the parameter space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the terminology, but it sounds like you're just asking whether, if you have an equation of the form ax + by = 0, does plugging in [a b] for [x y] always give a positive number? Of course, since aa + bb is just a sum of squared real numbers, and squaring real numbers always gives a non-negative number. And at least one if your coefficients a, b must be nonzero otherwise you aren't really defining a boundary.

EDIT: A "boundary" defined by an equation of the form ax + by + c = 0 passes through the origin if and only if c = 0 (just plug in x = y = 0 to see why this is the case), which is why I only considered equations of the form ax + by = 0, and not ax + by + c = 0.  The example the OP mentions has c = -3.

Comment: plugging [5 1] in the decision boundary 5x1+x2-3 = 0 gives a positive number, however if the offset was -13 instead of -3 the result would be negative and it means the weight vector points towards the negative number. I think offset determines it, which is really easy mathematically but i wanted to know if there is any proof to it(like the proof for weight vector being always perpendicular to the decision boundary)

Comment: See my edit.  You asked about boundaries which pass through the origin; 5x + y - 3 = 0 does not.